# GCP: instance listed via gcloud command but not described

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

How is the following possible?

```
➢  gcloud compute instances list
NAME                                                 ZONE        MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP  STATUS
my-instance-1  us-east4-a  n1-standard-8               10.16.22.11               RUNNING
my-instance-2  us-east4-a  n1-standard-8               10.16.22.12               RUNNING
my-instance-3  us-east4-a  n1-standard-8               10.16.22.13               RUNNING
(.venv)
~/Workspace/staging-env-configs  workablestg9 ✔                                                                                 1h40m
➢  gcloud compute instances describe my-instance-1
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.describe) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-b/instances/my-instance-1' was not found

(.venv)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your instance is running in your default zone "us-central1-b", you can simply do `gcloud compute instances describe <instance-name>` However, if your instance is not running in the defautl zone you have to provide the zone as well so you will do:

`gcloud compute instances describe my-instance-1 --zone us-east4-a`

If you look at the output: "The resource 'projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-b/instances/my-instance-1'" You can clearly see it's looking in your default zone us-central1-b